Creando un diccionario en python a partir de una lista
Hola chic@s soy nuevo en python y tengo esta duda. Como puedo crear un diccionario a partir de una lista con elementos repetidos y que los valores de las claves sean la cantidad de veces que se repiten los elementos?
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd']
El resultado debe ser: d = { a: 3, b: 2, c: 1, d: 1}
Intente esto pero no me sale:
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd']
d = {}
for x in lista:
   if x in d.keys():
       d[x] += 1
   d[x] = 1 

El resultado que me da es d = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1}

Saludos. Por algoritmo; el d[x]=1 siempre se ejecuta, es decir, sea que entre o no al if donde incrementas en 1 a un d[x] ya existente lo vuelves a colocar en 1;  por tanto el d[x]=1 debe estar en un else: para crear ese elemento e inicializarlo en 1.

El error es que sobrescribres d[x] al terminar el if, debería ser:
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd']
d = {}
for x in lista:
    if x in d.keys():
        d[x] += 1
    else:
        d[x] = 1

print(d)


Gracias @ArturoAlonso. Ahora que lo veo es un error muy inocente.

Como d[x] = 1 siempre se ejecuta al final de cada iteración, tu contador siempre estará en 1. Esa linea solo se debe ejecutar si el if no lo hace (si no existe la clave en el diccionario), o usas un else como te sugiere la otra respuesta o también puedes usar continue para pasar a la siguiente iteración del ciclo:
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd']

d = {}
for x in lista:
   if x in d:
       d[x] += 1
       continue
   d[x] = 1

print(d)

No uses dict.keys() para verificar si la clave existe, if clave in dict es más simple y eficiente.
También puedes prescindir del condicional y usar dict.get() con 0 como valor por defecto si la clave no existe:
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd']

d = {}
for x in lista:
    d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1

print(d)

o siguiendo la misma idea, usar collections.defaultdict:
from collections import defaultdict


lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd']

d = defaultdict(int)
for x in lista:
    d[x] += 1

print(d)

No obstante, si no es por aprendizaje, la biblioteca estándar de Python viene con una clase exactamente para eso, collections.Counter, que además de ser simple y eficiente tiene algunos métodos útiles como obtener el valor que más aparece:
from collections import Counter


lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd']
counter = Counter(lista)
print(counter)


Tengase en cuenta si la optimización importa: usar dic.get(x, ...) como reemplazo de un condicional no es el camino más optimizado cuando se usa con objetos mutables como listas. Por ejemplo, dic.get(x, []) crea una lista vacía incluso cuando el elemento está en el diccionario. En el caso del 0, este viene precargado en la memoria y, por lo tanto, no se crea el numero 0 en cada iteración. De todas formas, quizá esto cambie pronto con las optimizaciones que se le están haciendo al interprete.

@DanteS. si, ese es uno de los mayores inconvenientes de dict.get() si se usa con objetos mutables (ya que necesitamos pasar una referencia a un nuevo objeto en cada llamada). En este caso concreto, en cuanto a eficiencia, el orden debería ser collections.Counter > dict.get() > defaultdict > if-else. En el peor de los casos (lista con valores no repetidos) la ventaja de dict.get() se diluye y debería ser similar al condicional, defaultdict se comporta especialmente mal en este caso  si mal no recuerdo. En general, para este caso si la eficiencia importa: collections.Counter.
